# HTML SVG Elements not rendering properly:

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to display different SVG elements (line, ellipse, rectangle) in an HTML but facing this strange issue of elements getting cut and sometimes displaying in a blurred way (small cuts like saw blade). I tried giving different sizes of div and elements, positioning them differently but nothing seems to be working, check the following sample code:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:17pt; left:37pt; "> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  version="1.1"> 
<line id = "default" x1="0" y1="0" x2="16" y2="272" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width:7;"/> 
</svg> 
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; top:200pt; left:67pt; "> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"> 
<ellipse cx="83" cy="77" rx="83" ry="77" style="fill:none; stroke-width:3;stroke: rgb(0,0,0);stroke-dasharray:15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4"/> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

You can find the **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/b188dw2u/)**.. Am i doing something wrong or is it some internal svg issue. In case, you are not getting the problem in your browser, i am also attaching an image. (i am using Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SVGs have no assigned [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox). With the browser recognition of the size of an SVG sometimes making mistakes, just parts of the SVG get shown. The `viewBox` actually tells the browser which area of the infinite SVG plane it should actually show.

Furthermore, you have to give the `div` tags a `width` and `height` to be able to see the SVGs:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:17pt; left:37pt; width:100px; height: 300px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-10 -10 100 300">
        <line id="default" x1="0" y1="0" x2="16" y2="272" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width:7;" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:200pt; left:67pt; width:200px; height: 200px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="-10 -10 210 210">
        <ellipse cx="83" cy="77" rx="83" ry="77" style="fill:none; stroke-width:3;stroke: rgb(0,0,0);stroke-dasharray:15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

[**Corrected Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b188dw2u/1/)

---

Wrt to the "weird output" in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b188dw2u/2/) from the comments:

Suppose you are the browser. You should draw a line from 0,0 to 0,50 (for simplicities sake let us use a vertical line. the results are the same for your line modulo the rotation). So you go to 0,0 and start drawing, but the user also specified `stroke-width: 7`, so the actual line will be between -3.5,0 and 3.5,0 to result in a line of width 7.

In the next step you apply the `viewBox` that has been set, so you throw away anything outside of the rectangle 0,0 to 100,100. In particular this gets rid of half line you just draw as this half is not within the given `viewBox`.

To the user in the browser it seems that you have drawn a line of width 3.5 instead of 7, but you just did exactly what the user asked you to do ...

Comment: The problem is that div width and height is not known, i just know the 4 line points and stroke properties...

Comment: @AbdulJabbar You can remove the div dimensions, when also dropping the `position: absolute` (Although, the dimension the browser will assign, might not be, what you actually want). But for the `viewBox` you have to at least estimate the dimensions of the SVG. Else you can just rely on the browser estimates, which fail in your case (as seen in your fiddle)

Comment: I think, giving the width and height of div to 100% should be enough but how to estimmate the dimensions of divs from the 4 line points... i am trying different values and it is really showing weird outputs http://jsfiddle.net/b188dw2u/2/

Comment: @AbdulJabbar wrt to the weird output see my edit. As for the calculations - this is highly dependent on how you actually create that SVG.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications... well, what i did now is, giving the width and height of my actual page to all the divs and viewboxes along with min-x, y's -10. This seems to be drawing all the shapes perfectly (12 of them). I am not sure if it's a good solution or not? but it's working.. will i face any serious problems due to this or is it safe to proceed like this...

Comment: @AbdulJabbar Is there a particular reason to use a separate SVG for each shape? If not, I'd put them all into one. If you can't compute the actual dimensions somehow, this may be your only approach. It's not perfect, but seems to work.

Comment: Well yes, separate SVGs are a necessity because i am creating an HTML in C++ from string so whenever an SVG element comes i am creating this tag. Elements are coming in random order so can't just keep one block of SVG.. I'll try to find another way for that too. Thanks a lot for the help.